# Javascript : Formatting values on the presentation layer a good idea?

Tags: javascript, performance, formatting

Our application(UI) has to deal with presenting results of calculations (complex/simple). Each value/number has to be formatted either in terms of currency/quantity etc.  for display since we receive raw data from the backend. Currently we perform all these kind of formatting on the UI side using our own functions written in javascript. For example:

```js
formatAmount: function (value) {
  jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.format.NumberFormat");
  var oNumberFormat = sap.ui.core.format.NumberFormat.getFloatInstance({
    maxFractionDigits: 2,
    groupingEnabled: true,
  });
  value = (oNumberFormat.format(Number(value).toFixed(2)));
  return value + " \u20ac";  // € Symbol
},
```

As I went along with the development I realized that the UI included several formatting with multiple functions. Since we are doing the UI testing locally with sample data binded to the UI elements, I don't experience performance issues during display. But I have a bad feeling when I think about formatting large amount of data coming from the backend and presenting it on the UI.

So I would like to ask if it is a good idea to perform such formatting on the UI side or should I in any case handle this on the backend? Do you have suggestions how these value formatting could be avoided?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The answer will depend on your situation. If you need to reduce load on the client, format the values on the server. If you need to reduce load on the server, format the values on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to do it on the client like you are doing right now for following reasons:

- You have more flexibility with raw data on the client side. Especially if
  requirement changed and you need to present data in the user's locale, then it's easier to do it on the client than on the server side, since you already have client locale information
- it is much easier to do on the client side. Sending data to the
  client reduce load on the server and network side especially if you
  have a lot of users.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. But what is your opinion when we consider running the application(responsive design) on touch devices? I ask this because the processing power of notebook is higher compared to tablets or smartphones. Such load on the UI could show a great impact on touch devices from my opinion.

Comment: If you only adding currency (like you do it in your example) then formatting it on the client side is not going to impact performance on the client side. However if you are going to do much more complicated logic, then you might do it on the server side. Also if you are going with mobile devices, you might consider design of your application, since you don't want to have big pages. You might think about pagination, so your page will load fast.